# One-vs-rest vs one-vs-one multiclass probability validation: does it matter?

Tags: probability, categorical-data, multinomial-distribution, calibration, probabilistic-forecasts

Now that I have figured out how `rms::val.prob` works to the extent that I have written my own Python implementation, I would like to extend that idea to multiple classes (can only be in one class at a time).

Instead of checking if my dog vs cat problem gives me dogs $X\%$ of the time the claimed $P(dog\vert Data) = X\%$ $($and thus $P(cat)=100-X\%)$, I want to check if I get reasonable probabilities for $P(dog)$, $P(cat)$, $P(horse)$, and $P(alligator)$.

My initial thought was that, if I get that each of those four are giving probability values that align with which animal I observe, then that's all there is to it. If I observe an $animal$ $X\%$ of the time my $P(animal)=X\%$, then my probability values are telling the truth. That would be a one-vs-rest approach.

Is there a reason I should prefer a one-vs-one approach? How would that even work?

(I think it does not matter if I get that my four $P(animal)$ values are giving probabilities in line with what I observe, but it gets interesting if my $P(animal)$ values do not align with which animal I observe.)