# How to assess calibration of probability distribution for a multiclass model?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, multi-class, calibration, probabilistic-forecasts

I have a multiclass classifier (boosting model), and my goal is to have a good approximation of the actual distribution to the classes given my feature values.

I.e. suppose I have features $X$, and three possible classes/target ($A$, $B$ and $C$).
What I want is to have a good estimation of this discrete probability distribution conditioned on $X$, that is, I want the model to accurately predict these values:

$$P(target = A | X = x), P(target = B | X = x), P(target = C | X = x) $$

I have the predictions output of the model ( a vector of probabilities) and only the actual target for a given instance - In my use case I need to use the probability distribution itself (and not classify an instance to a single class), for example I want to use these predictions to calculate an expected value conditioned on these predicted probabilities (e.g. if the target is item bought on my store, each item has a price and I could have the expected revenue by averaging out the probabilities and the prices).

Now, I researched a little bit how to assess calibration for a multiclass, discrete scenario and didn't found any clear way to achieve this. I found [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/363019/176706) that mentions the Expected Calibration Error (ECE), but on my own research I found two types of metrics which seem to make sense as well:

1. Brier Score
2. Perplexity measure

Brier score seems more intuitive to me, and perplexity score I couldn't find any use outside NLP application domains. Any tips or ideas?

Comment: +1 If you’re into that paper by Guo discussed in your link, you might be interested in a [question of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/552533/247274) from about a year ago. // [A related question of mine from earlier this year](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/566059/247274)